# Modifying Many Custom PowerShell Objects

Tags: powershell

I have a list of several thousand custom PS Objects that are exported from another system, and all these custom objects are in a variable `$queryResult`. The system exports these objects with a field `time` that is in epoch time format in milliseconds (example: 1492536777453 = Tuesday, April 18, 2017 1:32:57 PM) . I need to change all of these `time` fields in the custom objects into human readable times. I already have a function that converts epoch time to human readable:

```
Function Convert-FromUnixDate ($UnixDate) {[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddMilliSeconds($UnixDate))}
```

I also figured out how to convert all of them, however this just returns a list of times(obviously), and I can't figure out how to update the actual custom objects:

```
foreach ($i in $queryResult.events.time){$humanReadable = @{};Convert-FromUnixDate $i}
```

My problem is I want to update the actual value in each PS custom object so that, when I export all the objects to an excel file for the end user, they are readable. Your help is very much appreciated!

EDIT

I forgot to mention what happens when I try to update the values. I tried this statement below:

```
$aqlQueryResult.events.starttime = Convert-FromUnixDate ($aqlQueryResult.events.starttime)
```

When I try that, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "System.Object[]", for 
"AddMilliseconds" to type "System.Double": "Cannot convert the 
"System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Double"."
```

I understand that I'm receiving this error because my conversion function expects a double, but how can I either change this to expect the correct data type, or find another way to do this?

Comment: Values are set using `=`. Where is it? (except for the unused hashtable)

Comment: You could use a combination of `Select-Object`, `Foreach-Object`, and `New-Object`, I guess this could be done in a single pipeline. You have the main parts of it already.

Comment: Thanks @FrodeF, that was a silly mistake! I've updated my post to reflect where I tried the `=`

Comment: Now combine the two samples. Your can't mass edit an array, try foreach :-)

Comment: .Net 4.6 has `[System.DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliseconds($UnixDate).LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with a bit of help from @FrodeF and @sodawillow, I have figured out how to update the values inside the actual objects! Below is the line I needed to add.

```
$queryResult.events | ForEach-Object {$_.time = (Convert-FromUnixDate ($_.time))}
```

Comment: You should avoid parens when calling a PowerShell function; it works for one parameter, but it won't work as you expect for multiple parameters, it will pass them all as the first parameter.